# ReflectionsException: Could not get type for name org.gradle.api.Plugin

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have implemented the custom Gradle plugin and it works, but during the Gradle build I have a `ReflectionsException: Could not get the type for name org.gradle.api.Plugin` because of Reflections scanning. Why class loader doesn't see the type?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.api.Plugin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
```

The custom plugin implements `Plugin<Project>` like below:

```
//CommonGradlePlugin
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project; 

public class CommonGradlePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why class loader doesn't see the type?

I suppose that gradle classes are not included in compile/runtime classpath, just because it's a build tool. That's why gradle classes cannot be found by Reflections.

You can exclude package with gradle plugin using Reflection's ConfigurationBuilder:

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
FilterBuilder filterBuilder = new FilterBuilder();

configurationBuilder.addUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage(PACKAGE_TO_SCAN));
filterBuilder
        .includePackage(PACKAGE_TO_SCAN)
        .excludePackage(PACKAGE_TO_EXCLUDE);
configurationBuilder.filterInputsBy(filterBuilder);

Reflections reflections = new Reflections(configurationBuilder);
```

Comment: for my case, it worked, but because of many places with Reflections usages, I think that it's better simply to move the package with gradle stuff from the base package away.

Also just as WA it's possible to add a gradle API dependency like below:
`implementation gradleApi()`